# Do I need always lock before read even if very occasionally write to the memory?

Tags: multithreading

I have a shared data structure that is read in one thread and modified in another thread. However, its data changes very occasionally. Most of time, it is read by the thread. I now have a Mutex (or RW lock) locked before read/write and unlocked after read/write.

Because the data rarely changes, lock-unlock every time it is read seems inefficient. If no change is made to the data, I can get rid of the lock because only read to the same structure can run simultaneously without lock.

My question is:

- Is there a lock-free solution that allows me changes the data without a lock?
- Or, the lock-unlock in read (one thread, in other words, no contention) don't take much of time/resources (no enter to the kernel) at all?

Comment: This may vary based on the language, OS, type of data, and the consequences of a stale or invalid read in your program.

Comment: @Rotem Thank you for pointing out the missing things. I am using C++ on linux. Stale read is OK, but not invalid read. The data type is a customized struct.

Comment: Re, "Is there a lock-free solution...?" Lock-free algorithms are highly dependent on the structure of the data and the nature of an "update." There is no generic "lock-free" sauce that you can simply add to any given data structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there's no contention, not kernel call is needed, but still atomic lock acquisition is needed. If the resource is occupied for a short period of time, then spinning can be attempted before kernel call.

Mutex and RW lock implementations, such as (an usual quality implementation of) `std::mutex` / `std::shared_mutex` in C++ or `CRITICAL_SECTION` / `SRW_LOCK` in Windows already employ above mentioned techniques on their own. Linux mutexes are usually based on `futex`, so they also avoid kernel call when it its not needed. So you don't need to bother about saving a kernel call yourself.

And there are alternatives to locking. There are atomic types that can be accessed using lock-free reads and writes, they can always avoid lock. There are other patterns, such as SeqLock. There is transaction memory.

But before going there, you should make sure that locking is performance problem. Because use of atomics may be not simple (although it is simple for some languages and simple cases), and other alternatives have their own pitfalls.

An uncontrolled data race may be dangerous. Maybe not. And there may be very thin boundary between cases where it is and where it is not. For example, copying a bunch of integer could only result in garbage integers occasionally obtained, if integers are properly sized and aligned, then there may be only a mix up, but not garbage value of a single integer, and if you add some more complex type, say string, you may have a crash. So most of the times uncontrolled data race is treated as Undefined Behavior.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My team is focusing on the locking problem. I am trying to figure out if it is potentially avoidable. RCU (Read-copy update) seems to be the one I am looking for. Thank you for your advise.

Comment: Sorry, not an expert in Linux, so cannot advise on RCU usage (as original question is broad, I tried to give generic answer, without considering specific OS/mechanism)